# Best algorithm for print all children's for tree element?

Tags: c++

I want to create a tree using smart pointers. The result is this structure:

```
struct TreeElement {
    int data;
    std::shared_ptr<TreeElement> parent;
    std::list<std::weak_ptr<TreeElement>> childrens;
}
```

Now I want to display all the children for a specific item. How to do it better? Using which algorithm? Example:

```
void PrintAllChildrens(TreeElement element) {
    for (auto& el : element.childrens) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Example I have tree:

```
       10
     1   2
    3   4 5
  6  7
```

I want for element with data 1 PrintAllChildrens(1):
Result:

```
      1
     3
    6 7
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but how can a node have two parents? And why do you pass a `TreeElement` *by value* to the print function?

Comment: What kind of tree are you making, and why two parents? Look into textbook tree traversal algorithms.

Comment: Here is more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: I don't understand this structure. You only have strong references to the parent but weak references to the children. So a leaf node without children has no strong references and gets deleted, then the parents of the leaves have not strong references that point at it and will get deleted. So you can only keep the tree alive by storing strong references to all leaf nodes from outside the tree structure? That seems weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are exactly 3 ways to visit/print a (sub)tree: in-order, pre-order, post-order.

The precise 'best' algorithm depends on the problem domain. In your case, it looks like you want in-order printing, which would be implemented by

```
void PrintAllChildrens(TreeElement element) {
    // Print current level
    std::cout << el.data << std::endl;
    for (auto& el : element.childrens) {
        if (auto child = el.lock())
            PrintAllChildrens(*child);
    }
}
```

You can adorn the output with any kind of indentation and prettification that you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function that can find a node in the tree and return a pointer to it then you can use it to call the printing function:

```
void PrintAllChildrens(int data)
{
    auto node = FindNode(data);
    PrintAllChildrens(*node);
}
```